# Money for good grades?

Tags: money

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is bribing children with cash incentives a good idea?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-bribing-children-with-cash-incentives-a-good-idea)

Is it appropriate?

Good, because action-result chain is clear? To get something, you should work; your work now is learning at school.
And it feels like game (you are collecting scores = dollars), and games motivate humans. Well, money even more.

Bad, because it is false motivation?
No interest in learning as such?

PS Someone with reputation over 150, please create tag 'grades'

UPD Looks like my question is subset of this one:
[Is bribing children with cash incentives a good idea?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-bribing-children-with-cash-incentives-a-good-idea)